# XFCE session starts with 4 empty terminals. How to have a clean desktop at startup?

Tags: xfce

When I start my session (XFCE desktop) I have four terminals opened in the desktop.
I would like to have a clean desktop at start up.
Which file should I edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rm -fr ~/.cache/sessions/*
```

and

```
 xfce4-session-settings
```

Look that the Point automatically save session on logout is not set

Comment: Thanks for your very fast answer! I checked before asking in settings and the it is set on "ask before exiting"

Comment: the option activated in settings was "preguntar al salir" (ask at exit)

Comment: deleting cache does the trick.... thanks...